# Client Server, designing protocol

Tags: java, jaxb, client-server, unmarshalling

I code client-server application on sockets, and i have task to design my own protocol. Client and server communicating with xml. I use JAXB library. Client perfectly write XML into output stream. But i can not read it in Server. Can you show how to reciev datas from client properly?

This is a `Client`:

```
public class Client {
    public static final String SERVER_HOST = "localhost";
    public static final Integer SERVER_PORT = 4444;
    public static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Client.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Welcome to Client side");
        XMLProtocol protocol = new XMLProtocol();
        Socket fromserver = null;

        fromserver = new Socket(SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fromserver.getInputStream()));

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fromserver.getOutputStream(), true);

        BufferedReader inu = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String fuser, fserver;

        while ((fuser = inu.readLine()) != null) {

            protocol.setComId((long) 0);
            protocol.setContent("Client content");
            protocol.setLogin("User");

            try {

                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(XMLProtocol.class);
                Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
                jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
                jaxbMarshaller.marshal(protocol, out);

            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                LOG.error("Error while processing protocol"+e);             
            }

            fserver = in.readLine();

            System.out.println(fserver);

            if (fuser.equalsIgnoreCase("close"))
                break;
            if (fuser.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
                break;
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        inu.close();
        fromserver.close();
    }

}
```

And Server:

```
package dataart.practice.server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Server {

    public static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Server.class);
    public static final String SERVER_HOST = "localhost";
    public static final Integer SERVER_PORT = 4444;
    public static Integer userCount = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        LOG.trace("Server started");
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);

        try {
            while (true) {
                LOG.trace("Waiting for connections...");
                Socket socket = s.accept();

                try {
                    new ServerThread(socket);
                    LOG.trace("Users in the chat: "+(userCount+1));
                    userCount++;

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    socket.close();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            s.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And my thread.

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ServerThread.class);
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private String buffer;
        public ServerThread(Socket s) throws IOException {
        socket = s;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
        start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {

            //  if ((buffer = in.readLine()).endsWith("</xmlProtocol>")) {
                    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(XMLProtocol.class);
                    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                    sXMLProtocol protocol = (XMLProtocol) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(in);
                    LOG.trace("Getting message from user" + protocol.getContent());
                }
                LOG.trace("Nop");
            }
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
                LOG.trace("Socket closed");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.error("Socket no closed" + e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What should I write on Server to parse XML that I get? I try to parse InputStream.

**`Edit my question:`** now it show me Exception. I change marshall parameter.

> DefaultValidationEventHandler: [FATAL_ERROR]: Element type "xmlProtent" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>". 
>            Location: line 2
>       javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
>        - with linked exception:
>       [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.]
>       DefaultValidationEventHandler: [FATAL_ERROR]: Content is not allowed in prolog. 
>            Location: line 1
>           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.SAXUnmarshallerHandlerImpl.handleEvent(SAXUnmarshallerHandlerImpl.java:870)
>           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ErrorHandlerAdaptor.propagateEvent(ErrorHandlerAdaptor.java:82)
>           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ErrorHandlerAdaptor.fatalError(ErrorHandlerAdaptor.java:58)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:180)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1375)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:996)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
>           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:160)
>           at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
>           at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
>           at dataart.practice.server.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:41)
>       Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
>           ... 16 more
>       javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Element type "xmlProtent" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
>        - with linked exception:
>       [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 12; Element type "xmlProtent" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".]
>           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.SAXUnmarshallerHandlerImpl.handleEvent(SAXUnmarshallerHandlerImpl.java:870)
>           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ErrorHandlerAdaptor.propagateEvent(ErrorHandlerAdaptor.java:82)
>           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ErrorHandlerAdaptor.fatalError(ErrorHandlerAdaptor.java:58)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:180)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1375)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.seekCloseOfStartTag(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1354)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:245)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3063)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:881)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
>           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:160)
>           at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
>           at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
>           at dataart.practice.server.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:41)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>       Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 12; Element type "xmlProtent" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
>           ... 23 more

Comment: Are you sure no data is read by Server or only this if block?

Comment: Server read data but it read only a string like <xmlProtocol>, than another field and so on. But i want to read buffer only once.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried debugging the line

```
    (buffer = in.readLine()).endsWith("</xmlProtocol>")
```

maybe its result is false

Comment: no it read. Server read all that client send to it. But i do not want to read Strings. I think It's a question about JAXB features.

Comment: i think i found it;
you call 
sXMLProtocol protocol = (XMLProtocol) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal();

without the Stream to unmarshal

Comment: I live it clear cause i really do not know what to write there. If i write "in" there, like inputStream it not work.